# React - cannot display svg images which path is stored in json file

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have a json file where I store paths for my svg icons and other information that I want to display. In a component I map over the data stored in that file. It displays all the data I store there except for the images. When I go to the following directory (the icons folder is in public folder) http://localhost:3000/icons/france.svg I can see the image so it means that the path is correct. Also when I imported directly one image (when icons folder is in src folder) to the component and used it in img src attribute also the svg image is displayed. Do you know how to fix it?
This is what I see
[image]

**json file structure**

```
 [
    {
        "id":0,
        "language": "English",
        "level":5,
        "img":"../../icons/uk.svg"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "language": "Spanish",
        "level":5,
        "img":"../../icons/spain.svg"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "language": "Italian",
        "level":4,
        "img":"../../icons/italy.svg"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "language": "French",
        "level":3,
        "img":"../../icons/france.svg"
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "language": "Portuguese",
        "level":2,
        "img":"../../icons/portugal.svg"
    }

]
```

**component code **

```
import React from 'react'
import './Styles.css'
import communicationImg from '../images/communication.svg';
import dataLanguages from '../data/languagesData.json'
import { faStar } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import img from '../../src/icons/france.svg'
function Languages()
{
   
  
 return(
     
        <div id='languages'>
            
            <h2>Languages</h2>
            <img className="images" src={communicationImg} alt="communicationImg"/>
            <div className="lang_content">
                {
                    dataLanguages.map((element)=>{
                        return(
                            <>
                            <div className="lang_container">
                                <div className="lang_img">
                                    <img className="lang_icon" src={element.img}/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="lang_label">{element.language}</div>
                                <div className="rating">
                                    {
                                         [...Array(element.level).keys()].map(()=><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar}></FontAwesomeIcon>)
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        
        </div>
    
 )
}


export default Languages
```

Answer (score 0):

With `webpack` you need to `import` images (if they not public i.e in `src` folder), [see docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/):

```
// Bad: src={element.img}
<img className="lang_icon" src={require(element.img)}/>
```

Or:

```
import ukImg from "../../icons/uk.svg"

[
    {
        "id":0,
        "language": "English",
        "level":5,
        "img": ukImg
    },
...
]

// Will Work
<img className="lang_icon" src={element.img}/>
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error :"Error: Cannot find module '../icons/uk.svg'"

Comment: But when I import the svg directly in the component like this (import img from '../icons/france.svg';) with the same path that is stored in json file and use the variable in the src attribute (<img className="lang_icon" src={img}/>)  then the svg is shown.